# Porque getChildNodes me da un resultado inesperado

Tags: java, nodejs, dom

Al obtener los hijos del nodo raiz(libros) deberia obtener como resultado 3( libro, titulo y autor) y me da 9 al aplicar getchildnotes();

**libros.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Libros>
 <Libro publicado_en="1840">
 <Titulo>El Capote</Titulo>
 <Autor>Nikolai Gogol</Autor>
 </Libro>
 <Libro publicado_en="2008">
 <Titulo>El Sanador de Caballos</Titulo>
 <Autor>Gonzalo Giner</Autor>
 </Libro>
 <Libro publicado_en="1981">
 <Titulo>El Nombre de la Rosa</Titulo>
 <Autor>Umberto Eco</Autor>
 </Libro>
 <Libro publicado_en="1982">
 <Titulo>El libro de la selva</Titulo>
 <Autor>Mariola</Autor>
 </Libro>
</Libros>
```

**Metodos.java**

```
        Node nodo; //Nodo del árbol DOM
        Node libros = doc.getFirstChild(); //Obtiene la raíz <libros>(doc es libros.xml)



        NodeList libro = libros.getChildNodes(); //Obtiene los hijos del raíz <libro>
        System.out.println(libro.getLength());
```

Al probar el codigo y monitorizarlo en la ultima linea me aparece como resultado 9

Comment: Yo seguí esta página para una tarea similar que tuve que hacer: https://www.journaldev.com/898/read-xml-file-java-dom-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que `libros.getChildNodes()` devuelve 4 nodos Libro(`ELEMENT_NODE`) mas 5 nodos de texto `TEXT_NODE` con el valor de `\n`, en total son 9.

El porque de esto ya lo conteste en tú pregunta anterior:

> Porque me aparece Nullpointerexception al guardar un atributo de un
>   nodo. [Ver respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/216419/107347).